# Removing/Adding the effect of third variable

Tags: correlation, partial-correlation

If two variables say X and Y with 100 observations are having a relationship(significant correlation) and we know that the third variable Z is having some effect on the that relationship.
Then how can we remove the effect of the Z from X and Y relationship and the other way round that is how can we add effect of Z in X and Y relationship?

Answer (score 2):

If I have well understood what you mean, in case you are using a regression (and therefore you are assuming a CAUSAL relationship of X on Y), you would simply have to insert an interaction term.

$ y = b_{0} + b_{1}*x + b_{2}*x + b_{3}*x*z $.

Therefore, $ b_{3} $ will tell you how the effect of X on Y changes because of Z.

Comment: I am generating data myself using a python program.I want my interaction term to be significant.My question is that what correlation structure should be present in my data before I run regression.

Comment: How is the use of a regression assuming a causal relationship?

Comment: For instance, if you want to study the effect of starting school one year later (x) on an international education test score (y), you are interested in this causal relationship (only x->y), not just in simple correlation (x<->y)